# How to replace nested props with a path provided as reference?

Tags: javascript

How to replace nested props with a path provided as reference?

Following is an object with some props and some main Props.

```
const obj = {
    items: {
        props: {
            prop1: {
                $ref: "#/items/props/Prop1",
            },
          prop2: {
            $ref: "#/items/props/Prop2",
          },
          prop3: {
            $ref: "#/items/props/Prop3",
          },
          prop4: {
            subItems1: {
              $ref: "#/items/props/Prop4",
            },
            subItems2: {
              $ref: "#/items/props/Prop4",
            },
          },
          prop5: {
            $ref: "#/items/props/Prop5",
          },
          prop6: {
            $ref: "#/items/props/Prop6",
          },
          prop7: {
            $ref: "#/items/props/Prop7",
          },
          Prop1: {
              nestedpropsFromProp1: {nestedSubPropsFromProp1: {}}
          },
          Prop2: {
              nestedpropsFromProp2: {nestedSubPropsFromProp2: {}}
          },
          Prop3: {
              nestedpropsFromProp3: {nestedSubPropsFromProp3: {}}
          },
          Prop4: {
              nestedpropsFromProp4: {nestedSubPropsFromProp4: {}}
          },
          Prop5: {
              nestedpropsFromProp5: {nestedSubPropsFromProp5: {}}
          },
          Prop6: {
              nestedpropsFromProp6: {nestedSubPropsFromProp6: {}}
          },
          Prop7: {
              nestedpropsFromProp6: {nestedSubPropsFromProp7: {}}
          },

        }
    }
}
```

expected result:

```
const exp_obj = {
    items: {
        props: {
            prop1: {nestedSubPropsFromProp1: {}},
          prop2: {nestedSubPropsFromProp2: {}},
          prop3: {nestedSubPropsFromProp3: {}},
          prop4: {
            subItems1: {nestedSubPropsFromProp4: {}},
            subItems2: {nestedSubPropsFromProp7: {}},
          },
          prop5: {nestedSubPropsFromProp5: {}},
          prop6: {nestedSubPropsFromProp6: {}},
          prop7: {nestedSubPropsFromProp7: {}},
        }
    }
}
```

The idea here is to replace

```
            prop1: {
                $ref: "#/items/props/Prop1",
            },
```

with the value from `$ref: "#/items/props/Prop1"` (wherever this value is required.. ie if the same path is referenced($ref) in multiple places all those places will get replaced)

so that we get `prop1: {nestedSubPropsFromProp1: {}}`

and the original pro (capitalized one e.g. `Prop1`) will be removed from the final result

**The only requirement is whenever you encounter $ref -> read it's corresponding value (ie {$ref: value}. This value will be the path to the real Prop. & just append that real Prop in the place where you saw $ref. That's it.! I've provided a sample expected result. please check that too!@**

Comment: are you using a json schema library or doing this all from scratch?  if from scratch, why?

Comment: I've a json schema. I want to extract only the required prop from that. Json schema has a lot of unwanted stuffs like description, example, type etc... I just want to remove all those stuffs & get only the required items.

Can you please suggest the best way to do it?

Comment: will all the paths be this simple?

Comment: No this is actually a simplified form. The original paths will be nested. But somewhat similar. You don't need to worry about that!

Comment: @reacggarav, please provide valid example, this one is not valid Prop2: {
              nestedpropsFromProp2: {nestedSubPropsFromProp2: {}
          }, closing bracket is missing

Comment: The only requirement is whenever you encounter $ref -> read it;s corresponding value (ie {$ref: value}. This value will be the path to the real Prop. & just append that prop in the place where you saw $ref. That's it.!

Comment: This is a valid object. Where is the problem?

Comment: @reacggarav, no, it is not, watch carefully starting from Prop2 brackets are missing

Comment: Sorry missed that one. Fixed it. Now it should work.

Comment: Made an update. Check that!

Comment: some of the paths are/were invalid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first you can replace all values and save paths
and then just delete paths

below is an example using `lodash` function `get`

```
const replaceRefs = obj => {
   const refs = new Set()
   const readProps = (currentObj) => {
      if (typeof currentObj !== 'object') return 
      for (const key in currentObj) {
         if (key === '$ref') {
            const refPath = currentObj[key].substr(2).replace(/\//g, '.')
            currentObj[key] = _.get(obj, refPath) 
            refs.add(refPath)
         } else {
            readProps(currentObj[key])
         }
      } 
   }

   readProps(obj)
   refs.forEach(ref => {
      const parts = ref.split('.')
      const key = parts.pop()

      delete _.get(obj, parts.join('.'))[key]
   })

}
```

Comment: Can you please update the code? (if it was not written properly, cause now I've fixed the typos)

Comment: @reacggarav, my code has nothing to do with your typos, nothing to update. Just foollow the idea and correct it a bit if it is not exactly what you need

Comment: Hi Dimitry,. Can you please answer this also?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62362111/how-to-transfer-props-of-an-object-from-one-location-to-another/62362652?noredirect=1#comment110295195_62362652

Answer (score 1):

Mutates on obj.  Uses a Map() to store [$ref]:references to objects.
Walks objects recursively to find $ref, and then traverse paths.
Assumes all paths are in format `#/path/path/...`

Note: You didn't specify how to handle invalid $refs.  I just replace them with undefined right now. Code was added to handle that, because paths in example aren't all valid.
Note: Same references will refer to the same object.  Mutating one of them will mutate all of the ones pointing to the same path.  This was deliberate.  Add cloning if you want to prevent this.

```js
const map = new Map()
walk = node => {
  if(typeof node!=='object') return
  Object.keys(node).forEach(k=>{
    if(!node[k]) return
    const {$ref} = node[k]
    if($ref) {
      if(!map.has($ref)){
        const dir = $ref.substr(2).split('/'),
              name = dir.pop()
        let ptr = obj
        for(const p of dir) if(!(ptr = ptr[p])) break

        map.set($ref, ptr && ptr[name])
        if(ptr) delete ptr[name]
      }
      
      node[k] = map.get($ref)
      delete node[k].$ref
    }
    else walk(node[k])
  })
}

walk(obj)

console.log(obj)
```

```html
<script>
const obj = {
    items: {
        props: {
            prop1: {
                $ref: "#/items/props/Prop1",
            },
          prop2: {
            $ref: "#/items/props/Prop2",
          },
          prop3: {
            $ref: "#/items/props/Prop3",
          },
          prop4: {
            subItems1: {
              $ref: "#/items/props/Prop4",
            },
            subItems2: {
              $ref: "#/items/props/Prop4",
            },
          },
          prop5: {
            $ref: "#/items/props/Prop5",
          },
          prop6: {
            $ref: "#/items/props/Prop6",
          },
          prop7: {
            $ref: "#/items/props/Prop7",
          },
          Prop1: {
              nestedpropsFromProp1: {nestedSubPropsFromProp1: {}}
          },
          Prop2: {
              nestedpropsFromProp2: {nestedSubPropsFromProp2: {}}
          },
          Prop3: {
              nestedpropsFromProp3: {nestedSubPropsFromProp3: {}}
          },
          Prop4: {
              nestedpropsFromProp4: {nestedSubPropsFromProp4: {}}
          },
          Prop5: {
              nestedpropsFromProp5: {nestedSubPropsFromProp5: {}}
          },
          Prop6: {
              nestedpropsFromProp6: {nestedSubPropsFromProp6: {}}
          },
          Prop7: {
              nestedpropsFromProp6: {nestedSubPropsFromProp7: {}}
          },

        }
    }
}
</script>
```