# How to transfer props of an object from one location to another?

Tags: javascript

Following is an object with some deep properties.

```
const InitialObj = {
    Store: {propsFromStore: {}},
    Market: {propsFromMarket: {}},
    GoDown: {propsFromDown: {}},
    fruits: {store_c: "Store", otherProp1: {store_e: "Store", otherSubProp1: {}}, otherProp2: {}},
    vegetables: {market_d: "Market", otherProp1: {otherSubProp1: {godown_r: "GoDown", }}},
    fancy:{store_t: "Store", market_d: "Market", otherProp1: {otherSubProp1: {godown_r: "GoDown", }}},
}
```

Where ever you see "Store", "Market" or "GoDown", it should get replaced with values from the following object - no matter how deep they are.

```
// these values are not separate. there are part of the above initialObj.
//These values should replace Where ever you see "Store", "Market" or "GoDown", no matter how deep they are.

// The following values should be obtained from the above initialObj. & Not as a separate object.

Store: {propsFromStore: {}},
Market: {propsFromMarket: {}},
GoDown: {propsFromDown: {}},
```

So that the final result will be:
expected result

```
// this is what we get when the initialObj is transformed
// note that after removing all the occurences of "Store"/ "Market" / "GoDown"; these values will be removed so that final result looks like this. (with all placeholders replaced"

const finalExpectedResult = {
    fruits: {store_c: {propsFromStore: {}, otherProps...}, otherProp1: {store_e: {propsFromStore: {}, otherProps...}, otherSubProp1: {}}, otherProp2: {}},
    vegetables: {market_d: {propsFromMarket: {}, otherProps...}, otherProp1: {otherSubProp1: {godown_r: {propsFromDown: {}, otherProps...}, }}},
    fancy:{store_t: {propsFromStore: {}, otherProps...}, market_d: {propsFromMarket: {}, otherProps...}, otherProp1: {otherSubProp1: {godown_r: {propsFromDown: {}, otherProps...}, }}},
}
```

**Note that this should replace all the deep occurences of "Store", "Market" or "GoDown" with corresponding values**

Comment: What is the rule to saparate `Store: {propsFromStore: {}},
Market: {propsFromMarket: {}},
GoDown: {propsFromDown: {}},` from the InitialObject? Is it caplitalization?

Comment: Yep. It is capitalization. An exact match.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious solution would be to simply recursively iterate over all object properties, however it might be unnecessarily complicated and time consuming for such a simple case. Assuming we want to replace all instances of values being strings like `"Store"` and so on, we could transform the object into a string and do a simple replace function on it's contents, turning it back into object afterwards.

```js
const obj = {
    Store: {propsFromStore: {}},
    Market: {propsFromMarket: {}},
    GoDown: {propsFromDown: {}},
    fruits: {store_c: "Store", otherProp1: {store_e: "Store", otherSubProp1: {}}, otherProp2: {}},
    vegetables: {market_d: "Market", otherProp1: {otherSubProp1: {godown_r: "GoDown", }}},
    fancy:{store_t: "Store", market_d: "Market", otherProp1: {otherSubProp1: {godown_r: "GoDown" }}}
}


// please note the existence of ":" in front of the searched term which ensures the replaced value is actually a value not a key of the nested objects
const replaced = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)
  .replace(/:"Store"/g, ": {\"propsFromStore\": {}}")
  .replace(/:"Market"/g, ": {\"propsFromMarket\": {}}")
  .replace(/:"GoDown"/g, ": {\"propsFromDown\": {}}"))

console.log(replaced)
```

Of course this solution would not work if the properties of your objects are more complicated / require their own custom serialization method. An example of such a situation:

```js
const obj = { x: [10, undefined, null] }

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj)); // logs `{"x":[10,null,null]}` effectively losing distinction between undefined and null

const replaced = JSON.stringify(obj, (k, val) => typeof val === "undefined" ? "undefined" : val );
console.log(replaced) // with custom replacer can keep information that would otherwise be lost

const rereplaced = JSON.parse(replaced, (k, val) => val === "undefined" ? undefined : val)
console.log(rereplaced) // gets it's undefined value back
```

Comment: Can you please provide a solution without any serialization/ stringification?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function to check if the key is one of "Store", "Market" or "GoDown" and replace it with the corresponding value.
If the value of the key is an object(typeof object) then recursively call the function and repeat.

```
const obj = {
   Store: {
       propsFromStore: {}
   },
   Market: {
       propsFromMarket: {}
   },
   GoDown: {
       propsFromDown: {}
   }
}
const whiteList = ["Store", "Market", "GoDown"]

const replacer = object => Object.fromEntries(Object
    .entries(object)
    .map(([key, value]) => 
        [key, value && typeof value === "object" ? replacer(value) : whiteList.includes(value) ? obj[value] : value ]
    )
)
var initialObj = {
    fruits: {store_c: "Store", otherProp1: {store_e: "Store", otherSubProp1: {}}, otherProp2: {}},
    vegetables: {market_d: "Market", otherProp1: {otherSubProp1: {godown_r: "GoDown", }}},
    fancy:{store_t: "Store", market_d: "Market", otherProp1: {otherSubProp1: {godown_r: "GoDown", }}},
}
const finalObj = replacer(initialObj)
console.log(finalObj) // desired output
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: No. Not like this. The initial object should include
```
const obj = {
    Store: {propsFromStore: {}},
    Market: {propsFromMarket: {}},
    GoDown: {propsFromDown: {}},
    fruits: {store_c: "Store", otherProp1: {store_e: "Store", otherSubProp1: {}}, otherProp2: {}},
    vegetables: {market_d: "Market", otherProp1: {otherSubProp1: {godown_r: "GoDown", }}},
    fancy:{store_t: "Store", market_d: "Market", otherProp1: {otherSubProp1: {godown_r: "GoDown", }}},
}
```

Comment: So that the final output will be :

```
const finalExpectedResult = {
    fruits: {store_c: {propsFromStore: {}, otherProps...}, otherProp1: {store_e: {propsFromStore: {}, otherProps...}, otherSubProp1: {}}, otherProp2: {}},
    vegetables: {market_d: {propsFromMarket: {}, otherProps...}, otherProp1: {otherSubProp1: {godown_r: {propsFromDown: {}, otherProps...}, }}},
    fancy:{store_t: {propsFromStore: {}, otherProps...}, market_d: {propsFromMarket: {}, otherProps...}, otherProp1: {otherSubProp1: {godown_r: {propsFromDown: {}, otherProps...}, }}},
}
```

Comment: Note: It should replace the placeholders "Store", "Market" or "GoDown" with corresponding objects from the initial object itself. It should replace all occurences of the above whitelisted items. And when all placeholders are filled/replaced, in the final output these should be removed.

Comment: "Note: It should replace the placeholders "Store", "Market" or "GoDown" with corresponding objects from the initial object itself. It should replace all occurences of the above whitelisted items. And when all placeholders are filled/replaced, in the final output these should be removed"......

When you will be removing it at the end, why not separate it first and then do all the updates. IMO this will simplify things. I am not getting your point.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a first function which will find which props should serve as references (Store, Market, GoDown), and use recursion on the others, with an auxiliary function:

```js
const InitialObj = {
  Store: {propsFromStore: {}},
  Market: {propsFromMarket: {}},
  GoDown: {propsFromDown: {}},
  fruits: {store_c: "Store", otherProp1: {store_e: "Store", otherSubProp1: {}}, otherProp2: {}},
  vegetables: {market_d: "Market", otherProp1: {otherSubProp1: {godown_r: "GoDown", }}},
  fancy:{store_t: "Store", market_d: "Market", otherProp1: {otherSubProp1: {godown_r: "GoDown", }}},
};

function hydrateObj(obj, keys) {
  const refs = keys.reduce((o, k) => ({...o, [k]: obj[k]}), {});
  return Object.entries(obj).reduce((res, [k, v]) => {
    if(!keys.includes(k)) {
      res[k] = hydrateObjAux(v, keys, refs);
    }
    return res;
  }, {});
}

function hydrateObjAux(obj, keys, refs) {
  return Object.entries(obj).reduce((res, [k, v]) => {
    if(keys.includes(v)) {
      res[k] = refs[v];
    } else {
      res[k] = hydrateObjAux(v, keys, refs);
    }
    return res;
  }, {});
}

const res = hydrateObj(InitialObj, ['Store', 'Market', 'GoDown']);
document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(res, 0, 4) + '</pre>';
```

Comment: Hi. I;m using typescript. Is there an alternative for Object.fromEntries?>> Error -> Property 'fromEntries' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'

Comment: I replaced `Object.fromEntries` with a `reduce`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments that you separate replacement object from InitialObj by capitalised first letter.

- Separate replacementObject from InitialObj
- Recursively replace key string based on replacementObject
  Note: I don't know what type you have, so I set `any` for every type. It better to define and set correct type if you'r using ts.

```js
const InitialObj: any = {
    Store: {propsFromStore: {}},
    Market: {propsFromMarket: {}},
    GoDown: {propsFromDown: {}},
    fruits: {store_c: "Store", otherProp1: {store_e: "Store", otherSubProp1: {}}, otherProp2: {}},
    vegetables: {market_d: "Market", otherProp1: {otherSubProp1: {godown_r: "GoDown", }}},
    fancy:{store_t: "Store", market_d: "Market", otherProp1: {otherSubProp1: {godown_r: "GoDown", }}},
  }
  
  const replacementDict: any ={}
  
  // take Store, Market, GoDown from InitialObj to replacementDict
  Object.keys(InitialObj).forEach(key =>{
    // Check if the first letter is capitalised or not
    if(key[0].match(/^[A-Z]$/)){
      replacementDict[key] = InitialObj[key]
      delete InitialObj[key]
    }
  })
  
  
  function converter(obj: any){
    if(typeof obj !== "object") return
  
    Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]: [any, any]) => {
      if(replacementDict[value]){
        obj[key] = replacementDict[value]
      }
      if(typeof obj[key] === "object"){
        converter(obj[key])
      }
    })
  }
  
  converter(InitialObj)
  console.log(InitialObj)
```

Comment: getting error value: => Type 'unknown' cannot be used as an index type.

Comment: I' m using typescript.

Comment: Are you using typescript?

Comment: can you fix it.

Comment: So better you need to include your type in the question.

Comment: Which one should be typed?

Comment: Store: {propsFromStore: {}} - these are objects

Comment: Did you defined any type for InitialObj, Store, Market, or GoDown? Which line (specify but actual code not line number) did you get that error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215917/discussion-between-reacg-garav-and-tony-nguyen).

Comment: No. I didn't assign any types for initialObj.

Comment: It's a big object.

Comment: Type will be inferred from it. Right/

Comment: Try my updated code. I add `any` type for every thing, It's better to set correct type for them.
Note: you should not make separate comments like that, you should group them up to make cleaner conversation.